# Power BI visual interactions/DAX calculations

Tags: powerbi, dax

My experience with DAX is rather limited so I've been playing around with it performing calcs and making visuals. I have done a fair amount of searching but haven't really found any good explanations for my specific use case.

To give a quick rundown, I am trying to calculate the VWAP for AAPL with the current data I have. The first visual I made finds the total volume per month (this will be used as my divisor). The second visual calculates the the typical price (PV) and typical price mult by volume (TPV)

My question is, can I take the sums from visual 1 and apply them to the second visual, i.e. take the TPV of Jan 3 (14,185....) and divide it by the sum of volume for month of jan (1,443...)?

[image: Data in question]

Comment: Also, I realize my calculations are not accurate (not using a running total for TPV), however, understanding the logic of how visuals can interact is what I am more concerned with.

Comment: Don't share your already-summarized visuals; rather, share some raw data (in copiable format, not pictures) together with your expected results.

Comment: Please don't use alphabet soup to describe your data, because people who could help likely have no idea what you're talking about when you do that.